# US citizen living and working in US for a Canadian company.

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, employment

I will be working for a Canadian software company remotely from my home in the US. The company doesn't have a US branch or presence.  How will the company pay me without a US division?  And will I only need to pay US taxes?  Will they need to withhold SS and other taxes?  Should I start an S-corp and not be an employee instead?

Comment: Ask your company: Do they employ other people this way? What happens for them?  There are a few options, but to figure out what's best for you, you should seek professional advice.

Answer (score 1):

> How will the company pay me without a US division?

Probably by check or wire transfer.

> And will I only need to pay US taxes?

Yes.

> Will they need to withhold SS and other taxes?

Unlikely. You'll be a 1099 contractor, essentially, from the US tax perspective.

> Should I start an S-corp and not be an employee instead?

You should talk to a tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) about this.